# prove the existence of $c\in \mathbb C$ such as $\mathcal F(g)=c\delta + {1\over2i\pi}V_p({\mathcal F(f)\over x}) $

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

> prove that it exist $c\in \mathbb C$ such as $\mathcal F(g)=c\delta + 
> {1\over2i\pi}V_p({\mathcal F(f)\over x}) $
>
> with $\mathcal F$ fourier transform , $f\in \mathbb D(\mathbb R)$ , $\delta$ dirac distribution , $g\in \mathbb D'(R)$ and :
>
> $$ g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)dt $$
>
> $$ \left\langle V_p\left({u \over x}\right),\phi\right\rangle = \lim_{\epsilon\to0^+} \int_{|x|>\epsilon}{u(x)\phi(x)\over x} dx $$

i couldn't start anything here as i've never encountered this type of problems before , anything  will be appreciated !

Comment: Shouldn't you have $ \epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+} $ in definition of $ V_p $ ?

Comment: yes a mistake !

Comment: Are you sure $c$ is nonzero ? Because thats not what I see apparently....or maybe any other typos ?

Comment: you mean c=0 is a solution ?

Comment: the question is talking about any constant i think .. as long as i prove it exist

Answer (score 0):

I may have some mistake in my work, but this is what apparently seems to appear, so you have to prove for any test function $\phi $
$$ \int_\mathbb{R}\hat{g}\phi dx = c\phi(0) + \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{\hat{f}(x)\phi(x)}{x}dx  $$
Now $ g'(x) = f(x) $, so we have $\hat{f}(x) = 2\pi ix\hat{g}(x) $, substituting this we have 
$$ \int_\mathbb{R}\hat{g}\phi dx = c\phi(0) + \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}  \int_{|x|>\epsilon}\hat{g}(x)\phi(x)dx  $$ This equivalently is 
$$  \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}  \int_{|x|\leq\epsilon}\hat{g}(x)\phi(x)dx = c\phi(0) $$

Comment: And this implies $\hat{g}=c \delta$ and hence $g=\operatorname{const }c$?

Comment: @Vobo That is where I am confused if the problem is given correctly, perhaps if $V$ is defined with a suitable re-scaling by $\epsilon$ such that $ 1/2\epsilon $ comes additionally in the limit then from Lebesgue Differentiation theorem we can have $ c = \hat{g}(0) $